# Why does VS Code 1.82.1 create HTML links in Notebook error outputs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have an IPython Jupyter Notebook in VS Code 1.82.1, and whenever I run a cell that has  errors, the notebook output renders the traceback's links as raw HTML like `<a href='...'...>...</a>`. Why is this happening? How can I get a fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug. See [Error traces show unrendered HTML href that makes them hard to read
#192605](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/192605). It's caused by a regression in Pull Request [Only create HTML elements for links in notebook error output. #190440](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/190440). The fix has been made in [prioritize html links since they can wrap other link types #192606](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/192606), and will be released as part of [VS Code 1.82.2](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/milestone/245). If you're itching to get it before 1.82.2 is release, the fix is also available already in the latest version of VS Code Insiders.

Fun facts: It's the Jupyter extension that parses tracebacks and inserts the anchor HTML markup for things like line numbers and such. Related source code for that is in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/blob/main/src/notebooks/outputs/tracebackFormatter.ts. Then VS Code's Notebook functionality parses that HTML and renders links.